# 3 card texas-hold-em hand

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

texas-hold-em 9 players, at the river we are headsup #1 has three cards QD,JD.9H #2 has AS,10C  board JH,8S,2D,4H, and 3C, #2 is the winner yes?

Comment: What is #2s third card? To me it looks like #1 is winning with a pair of Jacks, but it depends on what the third card is.

Comment: You guys are a big help, in Hold-em you can only have two card in hand so #2 is the winner.

Comment: Incorrect, #1 appears to be the winner with a pair of jacks, as I mentioned. This looks to be a game of Pineapple or Crazy Pineapple, in which case one of the hole cards should have been discarded.

Comment: If in fact you are playing Texas Hold'em (which is a two-card game), then player 1 has a foul hand and cannot win anything. If you are playing a three-card game, then that game's rules apply, whatever they might be (and rules differ among such).